Can we define a logical constant to be a symbol that has the same meaning in all minds?
I just looked up the definition of "logical constant" in Wikipedia, and I came across the following definition:
A logical constant is a symbol in symbolic logic that has the same meaning in all models, such as the symbol "=" for "equals".
I don't know what they mean by model, but if you substitute 'mind' for 'model' the resulting definition makes sense to me.  Even a fish has access to the meanings of 'not', and 'and'.
I do hold that the elements of logic are universal, in the sense that no one reasoning agent is privileged.  The logical connectives in particular have the same meanings in all minds.
So my question is, can we replace the word 'model' by the word 'mind', to define "logical constant"?

No, formal logic is not about psychology.

@mauro-who made the decision that formal logic is not about psychology?

When we say that the binary predicate symbol = is "constant" we mean that we do not change its meaning (equality) when we change context (interpretation).

Who made the decision that formal logic is not about psychology?    See Mill's psychologism vs Frege's logicism. Note particularly the recent reevaluations https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychologism/#RecReEva

a variable can also have the same meaning for all minds once it has been given a value, so a logical constant is not about minds specifically

@Mauro, a stone cannot reason.  Only a being with a mind can reason.   Therefore it doesn't appear to me to be wrong to hold that a mind is required to know logic.  Therefore the definition of logical constant as a symbol of symbolic logic that has the same meaning in all minds seems apropos to me.  I don't agree with Mill's psychologism, I agree with Frege's logicism.  Logic is independent of psychology, but reasoning is not.  To reason you need the meanings of the connectives, AND those meanings are the same in all minds.

Modern logic began in the late 1800 "disengaging" formal logic from mind and anchoring it to language. But Aristotle already [Pr.An, 24b19-24b22] started the inquiry into logic with language: "A deduction is a discourse in which..."

See Logical constants

Logical constants are called "constants" to reflect the fact that they have the same meaning across all logical expressions. Do they also end up having the same meaning in all minds? They certainly end up having the same meaning in the minds of those people who understand the definition! Each logical constant is given a definition, and to understand the definition is precisely to end up having the same meaning in your mind as anyone else who understands the definition.
However, we may understand the definition and see that it is wrong. Thus, to define “A implies B” as A ⊃ B is just wrong. There does not seem to be any problem with the negation ¬A, the conjunction A ∧ B, the disjunction A ∨ B, but defining the implication A → B as ¬A ∨ B is just absurd. This is not limited to propositional logic. Defining "Fx implies Gx" as ∀x(Fx ⊃ Gx) is just as absurd.
Thus, while it is easy to understand the definition of the implication A → B as ¬A ∨ B, thereby ending up with the same meaning in our mind as anyone else who understands the definition, we can see that this definition is just wrong.
We all inevitably have the same meaning in mind as to what the implication is, but defining "Fx implies Gx" as ∀x(Fx ⊃ Gx) is not meant to give the correct definition of the notion of implication that we all have in mind. Rather, ∀x(Fx ⊃ Gx) is a translation that is regarded as expedient. It is a crude and inaccurate model but nobody seems to have anything better to offer, so mathematicians just take it because they have nothing else.

I fail to see why the definition (if A then B)=not A or B is absurd.  It's meaning comes from observations of reality.  I hold up a bowl to a child, and say this thing is the bowl.  Then i place all of ome apples and all of some bananas in the bowl and say if the thing is an apple then the thing is in the bowl, and if the thing is a banana then the thing is in the bowl.  Then I take out all the bananas and say if the thing is an apple then the thing is in the bowl and if the thing is a banana then the thing is not in the bowl. This communicates the words, not, and.

All of the stuff about how a definition can be "wrong" is incoherent. I have no idea what you are getting at.

Then to communicate the meaning of OR, place some bananas in the bowl and say if the thing is in the bowl then the thing is an apple or the thing is a banana.  Then to communicate the equivalence if A then B = not A or B, all you have to do is say THE THING IS NOT AN APPLE OR THE THING IS IN BOWL.

@leepappas "It's meaning comes from observations of reality." Presumably, but many false theories come from the observation of reality. For the rest, sorry, I am unable to make sense of it. - 2. "Then to communicate the meaning of OR, place some bananas in the bowl and say if the thing is in the bowl then the thing is an apple or the thing is a banana." And that will be true.

@leepappas "to communicate the equivalence if A then B = not A or B, all you have to do is say THE THING IS NOT AN APPLE OR THE THING IS IN BOWL." And this is absurd, but I  have to concede that apparently many if not most academics don't realise it is. Drives me banana, but I'm not committed to the idea that the majority of academics are very bright. Still, your failure to see that it is absurd is not sufficient to prove that it is true. Apparently, all you just did, and all that any academic has ever done, is to say that you think it's obviously true. Clearly not enough.

@speakpigeon, If it is absurd then it implies a contradiction.  How does if A then B= not A or B imply a contradiction?  In the example I gave, the word OR was used to describe reality, namely "the thing is not an apple OR the thing is  in the bowl".  Inclusive OR can now be determined.  The child can determine the OR statement means the same thing as, "if the thing is an apple then the thing is in the bowl.". Both statements describe reality equivalently.  There is no contradiction.

@leepappas "If it is absurd then it implies a contradiction"And why would that be? - 2. "The child can determine the OR statement means the same thing as, "if the thing is an apple then the thing is in the bowl.". Both statements describe reality equivalently" No, they don't.

@speakpigeon, you aren't understanding the apple /banana/bowl scenario.whan all the apples are in the bowl and all the bananas aren't in the bowl, the child hears "if x is an apple then x is in the bowl. Than some bananas are placed in the bowl, and the child hears not x is an apple OR x is in the bowl.   Looking at the bananas in the bowl he sees they aren't apples, AND they are in the bowl. Thus he infers the word OR, is nclusive. He knows if x is an apple then x is in the bowl, AND [not x is an apple or x is in the bowl].  They are simultaneously true only if they have identical meaning.

@leepappas "the apple /banana/bowl scenario.whan all the apples are in the bowl and all the bananas aren't in the bowl, the child hears "if x is an apple then x is in the bowl." I agree that if all apples are in the bowl, then it is true that if it is an apple, then it is in the bowl. This is just what the conditional means.

@leepappas "Than some bananas are placed in the bowl, and the child hears not x is an apple OR x is in the bowl. Looking at the bananas in the bowl he sees they aren't apples, AND they are in the bowl. Thus he infers the word OR, is nclusive. He knows if x is an apple then x is in the bowl, AND [not x is an apple or x is in the bowl]. They are simultaneously true only if they have identical meaning." So when A → B is true, then ¬A ∨ B is true? Yes, I agree, and so I agree that A → B implies ¬A ∨ B. That still doesn't mean that A → B is logically equivalent to ¬A ∨ B.

@leepappas "If it is absurd then it implies a contradiction" Second time: Why would that be?

This answer is nonsense.

@NtLake "This answer is nonsense." Please elaborate, if you can.
